# AlarmManager + Dynamic broadcast cannot be received

Tags: java, android

1. **The dynamic registration broadcast in the code cannot be received, why?why?why?**
2. Register the broadcast in AndroidManifest.xml and receive it normally

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
i.setAction("test_action");
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10 * 6000, pIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` flag determines time when alarm will be triggered - in your case `10 * 6000` millis after **device boot**! your code is running probably after this moment, so you are setting alarm in the past...

try to add current `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` to your `10 * 6000` for getting moment in the future (1 min after code execution and alarm set up)

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60 * 1000, pIntent);
```

Comment: `Dynamic`  registration broadcast in the code cannot be received

Comment: thats not true, some of system broadcast can't be received in other way than dynamic registration (manifest declaration won't work)